# Is there way to bundle the adobe air application with a version of AIR that installs as a single executable?

Tags: apache-flex, installation, air

Is there way to bundle the adobe air application with a version of AIR that installs as a single executable?  Or do I need to ask the users to go to Adobe to install AIR, then install our application?

Comment: merv is right - Don't forget to select an answer as correct.

Answer (score 3):

It's called [Captive Runtime](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2011/08/10/air-3-0-captive-runtime/).